# Improve regex in vim to make mappings recursive

Tags: regex, vim

I have the following regex which converts text such as:

```
:nmap
nmap
vmap
```

Into its non-recursive form:

```
:nnoremap
nnoremap
vnoremap
```

The regex is:

```
:%s/^:\?[invc]\?\zs\zemap/nore
```

Or, another version if the leading `:` is first stripped:

```
:%s/^[invc]\zsmap\ze/\1norema
```

I'd probably rewrite this in another language such as:

- [`^:?([invc]?)map\s`](https://regex101.com/r/TCA5Rt/1)

[image]

What might be a better way to write it in vim?

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite the working pattern? What is wrong with it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the `\zs\ze` seems a bit odd to me, so thought there might be a better way to capture that.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "odd". `:%s/^\(:\?[invc]\?\)map/\1noremap` and `:%s/\v^(:?[invc]?)map/\1noremap` are just the same.

Comment: IMO, \ze or \zs one is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `very magic` mode with your expression:

```
:%s/\v^:?[invc]?\zs\zemap/nore
```

`\zs\ze` are totally fine.